# Gmail Emails Counts by Script

Tags: google-apps-script

I am trying to count all my emails, with the label " complete - others", with Google Scripts. The thing is, the query is not counting all the emails. If I look into the label, I have, at least, 21k threads, and the script counts me just 591 emails.

Do you know how can I do to get this corrected?

Thanks !

[image: label search emails.]

Code sample:

```
`function countMessages3() {

  var spreadsheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActive()
  SpreadsheetApp.setActiveSheet(spreadsheet.getSheetByName('Mails'))

  var threads = GmailApp.search('in:sent');

  var receivedCount = 0;


  for(var i=0; i<threads.length; i++)
  {
    receivedCount = receivedCount + threads[i].getMessageCount();

  }

  spreadsheet.getRange('\'Mails\'!B4').setValue(receivedCount);`
```

Answer (score 1):

I guess, the code that you have provided is searching messages in sent folder. To search messages in a label I think you do something like:

> 1.Get label using `getUserLabelByName()` https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/gmail/gmail-app.html#getuserlabelbynamename
>
> 2.Get all threads for that label using `getThreads()` https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/gmail/gmail-label.html#getthreads
>
> 3.Then aggregate messages count in each thread using `getMessageCount()`
> https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/gmail/gmail-thread.html#getmessagecount

Something like this :

```
var labelName = "complete-others";
var messageCount = 0;

var label = GmailApp.getUserLabelByName(labelName);
var threads = label.getThreads();
threads.forEach(function(thread) {
    messageCount += thread.getMessageCount();
});

spreadsheet.getRange('\'Mails\'!B4').setValue(messageCount);
```

Comment: Thanks. I got this error:  TypeError: Cannot call method "getThreads" of null. (line 52, file "Code")

Comment: That means gmail is not able to find any label with that name. Can you verify that you're giving correct name with correct case and all ?

Comment: @OctavioSchiff, from the screenshot attached it seems that the `labelName` is **complete-others** and not **complete - others**, the reason you are getting the `TypeError`. So you should only make the following update: `var labelName = "complete-others"`. Cheers!

Answer (score 0):

Here's a function that will count your emails.

```
function countEmailsWithLabel(query) {
  var n=0;
  var ts=GmailApp.search(query);
  ts.forEach(function(t,i){
    var ms=t.getMessages();
    n+=ms.length;
  });
  Logger.log(n);
  return n;
}
```

The problem of course is figuring what the search query supposed to be.  I have several test emails in a label I created as 'Q0/TEST'  but where I search in Gmail I see that the search is 'label:q0-test' which doesn't agree with my label.  So I tried searching with a search query of 'label:q0-test' and that didn't work.  So now I use the query with the label as I created it so that the search query is now 'label:Q0/TEST' and I get the correct result of 3. So I would recommend that you use the labels as you created them rather than what you see in search box of the Gmail search.

Actually I ran into this inconsistency a few weeks ago and I suspect it has probably caused some difficulties for new programmers.